# Integrate LWUIT with Blackberry JDE

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, blackberry-jde

I am trying to make an integration between LWUIT and Blackberry JDE. I am importing the  LWUIT .jar file into a library project and setting the dependencies of this library with another project. I am then creating a new LWUIT form and running the project. I am alwas getting a "ClassDefError".

How to integrate the LWUIT with blackberry? Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use NetBeans?. I suggest you can use NetBeans for Blackberry development with LWUIT. And you can easily [integrate Blackberry JDE with NetBeans](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html).

Comment: with netbeans I can develop native Blackberry applications?

Comment: So you can use NetBeans. Why you choosing Blackberry JDE?

Comment: You can use Netbeans with [BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) to develop native BlackBerry applications.

Comment: A slightly simpler way to support the BB in netbeans: http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/12/better-way-to-blackberry-and-misc.html